# The assessment (שומה) of the judges - how it's done?

Tags: halacha-theory, money, beit-din-court

There are a lot of Mishnayos and Gemoros discussing שומת דיינים. E.g. [Kesubos 99b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ketubot.99b.16?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he):

> "מתני׳: **שום הדיינין שפיחתו שתות או הוסיפו שתות מכרן בטל**"
>
> "The assessment of the judges of the value of a piece of property in order to sell it is as follows: Where they decreased the price by one-sixth of its market value or added one-sixth to its market value, their sale is void."

I've read a lot of Meforshim inc. Rambam (Hilchot Mechira) and could not find a clear description of the process of assessment, especially how it can lead to gross errors.

I'm looking for a Halachic summary of how it is done, what people are involved, what estimates are taken into account, who sets the nominal or market value etc.